# Чтение данных с поврежденного диска

Tags: windows, железо

История: с утра винда выдала несколько BSOD-ов подряд с разными ошибками. Обычно если винда выкидывала такие сюрпризы, я просто дрова менял и всё. Тут же оказалось что полетел хард. Теперь его и биос только через раз видит.

Вопрос: Скажите, реально ли восстановить данные с (пока ещё полу-)убитого харда. "Полу", потому что иногда его система видит. Даже ОС загружается. Пока его не трогаю, дабы не убить окончательно. Что посоветуете?

Comment: Многоуважаемый хэшкод, который так и не сделал ничего с проблемой отправки комментариев, очень Вас прошу не удалять и не закрывать вопрос хотя бы на 1 сутки. Я понимаю что у Вас есть ещё 1 ресурс, но по словам хэшкодовцев биткодовцы крайне неактивны=\

Comment: @Виталий Кустов, "они" неактивны потому, что вы настаиваете на том, чтобы задавать вопросы здесь, а не там.

Comment: сегодня отнёс. Сказали что можно восстановить - то восстановят. Правда времени на это черт знает сколько может уйти. @avp, преобразуйте коммент в ответ. Вы сказали именно то, что я хотел услышать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@Виталий Кустов](/users/1048/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2), судя по ответу [@stranger](/users/7069/stranger) восстановить можно.

У меня был один знакомый, они восстанавливали (иногда частично) даже физически разбитые диски.

Так что ищите. Мастера есть.

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем понятно, что там хард выдает, но если речь про т.н. синий скрин смерти, то там есть строка - stop: бла, бла, и дальше цифры в скобках... это и есть код ошибки, два последних символа 1 числа, (точно не помню, смотрите расшифровку, типа 7а, 7f,7c, 0c, 0f и т.д. если, то это связано с файловой системой).

Не факт, что харду кирдык. Проверьте ленту интерфейса и разъем на hdd, может контакты загнуты или внутрь ушли, когда ленту в хард вставляли. У меня такое было, в биосе детектился не пойми как, вместо названия и модели непонятно что писал. Если все ок, дайте на него питание и слушайте и щупайте, как головки распаркует. Если все четко и биос его нормально детектит, но с загрузкой системы беда - грузитесь с системного multiboot типа ZVERDVD и выбирайте установку системы в ручном режиме.

Входите в консоль восстановления, выбираете, в какую ОС входить и даете команду `chkdsk [disk:] /r` и пускай чекер пока не напишет, что сканирование прошло без исправлений. Если не выходит или другая ось, можно использовать спецутилиты paragon, acronis (acronic есть на "звере" и восстанавливает данные, удаленные и форматированные разделы, но им лучше прогонять харды без ошибок). Если хард битый, можно прогнать HDDRegenerator'ом он восстанавливает разметку, не трогая данные.

Есть еще MHDD и  Victoriya и pc3000. Позволяют работать не просто напрямую на низком уровне "по железу", но и прописывать править микрокод (прошивку) и спецмодули с сервисной инфой. С ними нужно не просто внимательно, но и очень осторожно. И только если есть достаточно опыта, навыков и знаний.

Comment: @stranger Уважаемый участник, придерживайтесь стилистики общения, принятой на форуме.